# Accessing a mail with Gmail with php and changing the folder

Tags: php, email, gmail, directory, imap

I access to gmail using php to make action on mail. I put these mails into a folder using gmail directly.
So here is my code to get it :

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}test';
$username = 'myaddress@gmail.com';
$password = 'mypassword';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
//$emails = imap_search($inbox,'RECENT');
print_r($emails);

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    $emailCount = 1;
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

    //echo 'email n∞' . $emailCount;
    /* get information specific to this email */
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox,$email_number);
        if (!$overview[0]->seen) {
             print_r($overview);
             $emailCount++;
        }
    }
 // echo $output;
}
/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);
```

No I'd like to move these mail into an other folder, for exemple test2
here is what I do :

```
imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number, 'test2') or die('Error');
```

but I get an error :
Notice: Unknown: [TRYCREATE] No folder test2 (Failure) [THROTTLED] (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

I have tried these different kind of solution :
With a subfolder of test named test3

```
imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number, 'test3') or die('Error');
```

same error.
Also tried :

```
imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number, '[Gmail]/test3') or die('Error');
```

Same error :-(

If anyone has a solution that would be cool !

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Haven't used php for years, but have you tried printing out a list of the available folders? getmailboxes something similar

Comment: Good idea, and I discover this function. It returns me {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}test2 but even when trying with this I have the same error :-(

Comment: Try {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl} as hostname and then move to 'test2' (folder must exist I think)

Comment: {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl} or {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl} gives the same result Unknown: [TRYCREATE] No folder {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}test2 (Failure) [THROTTLED] (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
:-(

Comment: I'm out of ideas atm. The only thing I can think of is the read/write permission. Don't know how to grant it in PHP but might be the problem...

Comment: I've even try {imap.gmail.com:993/ssl}../test2 !!

Answer (score 0):

So after several tries here is what I have found that works :

```
imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number, 'INBOX') or die('Error');
imap_mail_move($inbox, $email_number, 'test2') or die('Error');
```

But that means to move to the inbox then to the second folder. Problem : the message is still in the inbox after these.

Still looking for an other solution.